# What to use instead of database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

My little website runs on asp.net 3.5 and I have not any sql server to host my db.
But some content of the website has to be changeable. 
( title of website, copyright - year etc. )

I don't want to open let's say "default.aspx" file and change whatever I want.

I should read/write these kind of information to files.

( *I'm sure somebody asked that question but I can't find it* )

What is the proper way to do it ? [xml, textfile, config file, or ? ]

Comment: If your data and site are simple, I recommend config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the data you need to store..

If we're talking about stuff like title, copyright etc, any kind of db is an overkill and a simple config file will do.

However, if you need to store complex data, like a list of your employees, you may need something more sophisticated. There are couple of options: portable db (e.g. SQLite) or maybe some kind of a file-storage. You can store data in a plain text without any special encoding (useful if you want to have editable text (`About me`)), or you can use json/xml and stuff like that (if your data is structured, like the list of employees I've mentioned earlier).

There's no "universal proper way", you have to adapt to your specific needs and options (hw/sw).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can use textfile it's very easy to edit. But for every visitior the "page.cs" should go and read values and show them. It's not faster like using sql. And i can't CHANGE the text if "file in use". Am I right ?

Comment: @LostInLib, to address your first concern, you can always use some kind of a caching mechanism if it performs slow. That is if you don't change the contents every minute... Well, and that second question of yours - depends on what you're actually going to do and how expensive your actions will be. If anything goes badly and you start seeing some problems, you can always implement a way of putting your website into an "offline" mode for other visitors, update what's needed and put back everything online.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to change content in the site then the web.config (or another config file) is the way to go.  If there is dynamic content that can be interactively edited I would suggest a NoSQL Db.  Something like [RavenDb](http://ravendb.net/) (only because it to is in C#).

To make this work you need access to the file system, the install for RavenDb is unzip and click on the cmd file.

Answer (score 1):

if you haven't database server, maybe you can think about SQL Lite (the best option), Json file, or XML (the worst option).

Answer (score 1):

The `web.config` file would work here. You can specify your information in the `appSettings` section:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="WebsiteTitle" value="MyWebsiteTitle"/>
</appSettings>
```

And then read it back out like this:

```
string websiteTitle = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebSiteTitle"];
```